# Typescript: a function that takes an array of strings and return an object whose keys are the values of the input

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get this function properly typed:

```
function genRandom(keys) {
    return keys.reduce(function (res, k) {
        res[k] = Math.random()
        return res
    })
}

const x = genRandom(['a', 'b']) // has type {a: number, b: number}
```

I've tried [this approach](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Numberize%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20genRandom%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20Numberize%3CT%3E%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(keys%3A%20K%5B%5D)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20keys.reduce(function%20(res%2C%20k)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20Math.random()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20res%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%20as%20T)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%20genRandom(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0A) without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one type parameter to hold the union of keys. The mapped type you defined is pretty much equivalent to `Record`

```
function genRandom<K extends string>(keys: K[]): Record<K, number> {
    return keys.reduce(function (res, k) {
        res[k] = Math.random()
        return res
    }, {} as Record<K, number>)
}

const x = genRandom(['a', 'b']) // { a: number, b:number }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! My account is too young for the vote to show up, but I did click the "up" arrow.